# Locking table while inserting in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, laravel-5

I am working on **laravel 5.1** and my mysql version is **5.5.44**.

My database storage engine is **innoDB**

I want to lock my table while inserting data into table as I have to acheive concurrecny because there can spawn multiple instances of server at same time (**because of load balancer of aws**) with single database.

I have studied [mysql locking](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/internal-locking.html) which explains storage engine must be MyISAM or MEMORY, or MERGE and also [pessimistic locking in laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#pessimistic-locking). Which

```
sharedLock() and lockForUpdate()
```

But it is not clear to me either they can do lock table or not..

**Question :** How can I acheive concurrency in this scenario ? Allowing only one insertion in table at one time. What steps do I have to follow ?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Use `lockForUpdate()` to instead prevent rows from being modified or selected with another shared lock.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. They need to know how to lock the table when inserting new records, not updating existing ones.